# Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer exception when calling NativeMap getter

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a custom map renderer in my Xamarin Forms project which was working without any issues. However I am getting the exception outlined below intermittently.

Could anyone tell me how I can handle/resolve this?

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>
> Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer.get_NativeMap():0
>
> Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer.UpdateVisibleRegion(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.LatLng pos):0
>
> Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer.OnCameraChange(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.CameraPosition pos):0
>
> Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap+IOnCameraChangeListenerInvoker.n_OnCameraChange_Lcom_google_android_gms_maps_model_CameraPosition_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_position):0
>       (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:147fbd37-e0e3-4bcf-a8c6-a4d48c833aa4 (intptr,intptr,intptr)

I found this Bugzilla article https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44174 which suggested adding  "null conditional operator", but where?

For info I am using version 2.3.3.180 of Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Here is my code:

This is the Droid Renderer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using MyProject.Mobile.Controls;
using MyProject.Mobile.Droid.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.Mobile.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer,     GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        GoogleMap map;

        public CustomMapRenderer() : base() { }

        public CustomMapRenderer(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) { }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;
        map.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view = null;

            // Do something

            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

This is the CustomMap class in the

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace MyProject.Mobile.Controls
{
    public class CustomMap : Map
    {
        // Do something custom
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of the control in Xmal

```
<controls:CustomMap x:Name="LocationMap"
              IsShowingUser="true"
              MapType="Street"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HeightRequest="300"
              WidthRequest="700">
    </controls:CustomMap>
```

Comment: Could you please share some code and steps so I can reproduce this issue? I tried to customize a MapRenderer, but I couldn't reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have now added my custom control code. When the page loads the exception is thrown

Comment: I tested your code many times on my android 4.4 emulator, in debug mode it works fine. Sorry couldn't help much.